# Updating dataframe based on conditions (over loop) R

Tags: r

I'm having difficulty developing a function/algorithm that that updates a dataframe based on certain conditions. I've looked at some answers related to "updating" a dataframe via for loops, but I'm still stuck.

Say I have a dataframe:

`df <- data.frame("data_low" = .2143, "data_high" = .7149)`

- where data_low and data_high are the max and min of some column in a dataframe

I also have two functions:

`checker(b[1,])`

- Takes the value of data_high and data_low, and returns a scalar. If the scalar is less than 1, I'd like to store this in another dataframe, say "d". Else, I want to split "b" with the following function:

`splitter()`

- splits "b" by the median of data_high and data_low.

I've considered trying to develop this with a loop:

```
storage <- data.frame(data_low = double(), data_high = double()

for( i in 1:nrow(b)){

     if(checker(b[i,]) <1){
         storage <- splitter(b[i,])
         
     } else {      
     temp <- splitter(b[i,])
     
     b <- rbind(b,temp)
            } 
     }
```

My desired output after two iterations (where check >1  for each row:

** Obviously these numbers are picked at random, I'm just hoping to gain some intuition related to looping/updating dataframes based on cases..

```
starting at i = 0:

| .2143 | .7149 |,

i = 2 
| .2143 | .4442 | ** Note at splitter() should break this into 2 rows after i = 2 is complete.
| .4442 | .7149 | ** And again here

i = 3

| .2143 | .3002 | 
| .3002 | .4442 |
| .4442 | .5630 |
| .5630 | .7149 |
```

Can anyone give me some tips on how to organize this loop? I'm thinking my issue here is related to rbind and/or the actual updating of b.

I recognize that much of this code isn't reproducible, but am more interested in the though process here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you need a loop. All of this can be vectorized. First construct checker so that it takes the low and high values and returns a logical vector. Use that vector to extract the selected rows to `d`. Then remove those rows from the original data frame and compute a vector of medians. Use that to split out the two groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a nested loop (one for the number of iterations and one for the number of rows in b), or using nested Reduce calls, as shown here.

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {
  List=apply(x, 1, function(z) {
    med=median(c(z[1], z[2]))
    dat=data.frame(data_low=c(z[1], med), data_high=c(med, z[2]))
    rownames(dat)=NULL
    return(dat)
  })
  Reduce(function(w, z) rbind(w, z), List)
}, rep(NA, 2), init=df)
```

One rep:

```
  data_low data_high
1   0.2143    0.4646
2   0.4646    0.7149
```

Two reps:

```
  data_low data_high
1  0.21430   0.33945
2  0.33945   0.46460
3  0.46460   0.58975
4  0.58975   0.71490
```

Three reps:

```
data_low data_high
1 0.214300  0.276875
2 0.276875  0.339450
3 0.339450  0.402025
4 0.402025  0.464600
5 0.464600  0.527175
6 0.527175  0.589750
7 0.589750  0.652325
8 0.652325  0.714900
```